# Проверка почты на существование mail.ru

Tags: php, email

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт написанный на php для проверки почты на существование, но проверить mail.ru почту не удается (всегда пишет, что не существует).

[Сам скрипт](https://pastebin.com/yUDepq0q)

> Возвращает true/false в зависимости от существования почты.

```
$alter->execute($str);
```

---

Сам вопрос, возможно вообще реализовать проверку mail.ru / доделать этот скрипт?
Скрипт нужен для очистки своей базы сайта от "мертвых" юзеров

Answer (score 5):

Если коротко - нет, если более детально, то, что вы хотите сделать не имеет смысла. За последние годы почтовые системы, такие как Mail.ru или Yandex, научились вылавливать "спамеров" своими алгоритмом (не важно являетесь ли вы таким или нет). Несколько лет назад, можно было скриптом `PHP` проверять валидность электронных адресов, отправляя запрос "Hello" и получая результат. В настоящее время почтовые сервера при такой проверке или всегда отвечают, что такого пользователя нет или наоборот, на все адреса отвечают, что все валидные, и когда вы начинаете радостно отправлять письма на эти "валидные" адреса, почтовые сервера, "хихикая )) "  банят ваш IP и...  конец счастливой рассылке.  Даже платные программы,например как  `Atomic Mail Verifier` или продукты `E-pochta`, в основном так же выдают ложный результат, который получают от mail.ru или yandex и т.д
Вторая очень важная деталь, при использовании баз адресов для рассылки, очень многие попадают в ловушку... а точнее в `Спам ловушки`, что в основном используют все известные почтовые системы. Если попасть в такую ловушку.. вы точно не отделаетесь простым попаданием ваших писем в спам, вас забанят "с ног до головы"
Детально о Спам ловушках можете почитать [тут](http://www.epochta.ru/blog/email-marketing/lovushki-dlya-spama-spam-traps/)

> Как проверить вашу базу ?

честным путём, зарегистрируйте ваш домен в супер ресурсе [postmaster mail.ru](https://postmaster.mail.ru/). настройте всё там и начинайте отправлять маленькими группами письма, и каждый раз получая ответ о невалидном адресе, тихо удаляем его из базы.

Comment: Дело в том, что с яндекс работает ок, все яндекс почты которые были отфильтровались хорошо. То же самое и с gmail и т.д., а вот mail.ru не дает такой возможности

Comment: @Владимир, если какой то ресурс (Яша или Гугл), при правильном запросе, и возвращает правильный результат, то к Mail.ru это не относится, mail.ru почти на 100% будет высылать ложные результаты, у mail.ru своя собственная политика....